# Create lists from columns, preserving duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get lists that contain every item in an order. My data is in the format of one order per row, with possible items as columns and the number of each item as a value.

I've worked out a way to do this for unique items, but I'd really prefer it if duplicated items were included multiple times. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd 

# Example dataframe
data = {'Egg':[0, 2, 1], 'Toast':[2, 2, 1]} 
breakfast = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# Cycle through columns and replace numbers with food words
value_cols = list(breakfast)

for food in value_cols:
    breakfast.loc[breakfast[food] != 0, food] = food

# Create a list of foods
list_of_foods = breakfast.values.tolist()

# Remove empty values
list_of_foods = [[x for x in y if x != 0] for y in list_of_foods]
```

This gives a list of lists like this:

```
[['Toast'], ['Egg', 'Toast'], ['Egg', 'Toast']]
```

However, I really want a list of lists like this:

```
[['Toast', 'Toast'], ['Egg', 'Egg', 'Toast', 'Toast'], ['Egg', 'Toast']]
```

I can't really think how to achieve this. I wondered about duplicating rows where there are duplicate items but then I would also duplicate non-duplicate items in the same order I think. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is loop by each row, zip by columns names and repeat values with flatten nested lists:

```
list_of_foods = [[c for a, b in zip(v, breakfast.columns) for c in [b] * a]
                  for v in breakfast.values]

print (list_of_foods)
[['Toast', 'Toast'], ['Egg', 'Egg', 'Toast', 'Toast'], ['Egg', 'Toast']]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not pretty but I think it works:

```
data = {'Egg':[0, 2, 1], 'Toast':[2, 2, 1]} # keys are dishes, values are frequencies

out = []
for i in range(len(list(data.values())[0])): # iterate over number of orders (num of frequencies)
    out.append([]) # new list for each order
    for key in data.keys(): # iterate overy dishes
        out[i].extend([key for i in range(data[key][i]) ]) # replicate dish a given amount of frequencies
```

This gives me: 
`[['Toast', 'Toast'], ['Egg', 'Egg', 'Toast', 'Toast'], ['Egg', 'Toast']]`

Encapsulate it in a function and there you go

Comment: Thanks, this worked too but jezrael's suited my data format of a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Series.repeat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html)

**Code**

```
breakfast.apply(lambda x: list(x.index.repeat(x)), axis=1).tolist()
```

**Output**

```
[['Toast', 'Toast'], ['Egg', 'Egg', 'Toast', 'Toast'], ['Egg', 'Toast']]
```